# Render a select list of provinces for Model.Province (string) property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to render a select list of provinces so the user can select a province. But the selected result that is returned to the server is always the first item of the select list (Ontario).

**Model** (Code first)

```
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Customer { get; set; }
    //[InverseProperty("BillingAddress")]
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Billings { get; set; }
    //[InverseProperty("ShippingAddress")]
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Shippings { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

My provinces are loaded in the ViewData like this:

```
string[] provinces = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CanadianProvinces"].Split(',');
ViewData["Provinces"] = new SelectList(provinces);
```

**View**

In my view I render my list like so, which does render a list correctly but the binding seems to fail... Since the first item is always returned even if the selection changed.

```
<div class="form-group required">
   <label for="Province">Provinces <sup>*</sup> </label>
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Province, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Province, (SelectList)ViewData["Provinces"],new {@class="form-control" })
</div>
```

**Generated Html**

Razor generates the following html:

```
<div class="form-group required">
   <label for="Province">Provinces <sup>*</sup> </label>
   <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Province" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
   <select class="form-control" id="Province" name="Province" style="display: none;">
      <option selected="selected">Ontario</option>
      <option> Quebec</option>
      <option> Nova Scotia</option>
      <option> New Brunswick</option>
      <option> Manitoba</option>
      <option> British Columbia</option>
      <option> Prince Edward Island</option>
      <option> Saskatchewan</option>
      <option> Alberta</option>
      <option> Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
 </select><div class="minict_wrapper active">
 <input type="text" value="Ontario" placeholder=" Nova Scotia">
 <ul style="display: block;">
   <li data-value="Ontario" class="minict_first">Ontario</li>
   <li data-value="Quebec" class=""> Quebec</li>
   <li data-value="Nova Scotia" class="selected"> Nova Scotia</li>
   <li data-value="New Brunswick" class=""> New Brunswick</li>
   <li data-value="Manitoba" class=""> Manitoba</li>
   <li data-value="British Columbia" class=""> British Columbia</li>
   <li data-value="Prince Edward Island" class=""> Prince Edward Island</li>
   <li data-value="Saskatchewan" class=""> Saskatchewan</li>
   <li data-value="Alberta" class=""> Alberta</li>
   <li data-value="Newfoundland and Labrador" class="minict_last"> Newfoundland and Labrador</li>
   <li class="minict_empty" style="display: none;">No results match your keyword.</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to figure out why 2 lists (1 select list and 1 < ul > list) are rendered with an input type text. Any solution or help to find clues toward a solution are welcome and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any plugins? or did you override the DropDownListFor implementation?

Comment: Yeah Jqueryminimalect was the cause. I just answered the question, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the reason, I am using a website template which happens to be using jquery minimalect plugin. The script is breaking the property binding when it replaces the rendered select list. I removed the script reference and now it is working fine...